# Displaying Difference of an XML file in HTML format

Tags: java, html, xml

I am working on this code to show the differences in two files in an HTML format .I am doing it in Java . This is what i have done so far .
  1. I am reading the file contents into String Arrays .
  2. Using LCS algorithm to find the longest sub sequence matrix mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-mMvhfJhu8)
  3. Use a string builder to create Html head 
  4. Using the LCS matrix , append the strings to the string buffer.
  5. if there is a difference in two strings i change the tr bgcolour to show it in a different color.

This works perfectly fine when i use a normal text file .

code snippet :

```
        sb.append("<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>");
        sb.append("<td>");
        sb.append( x[i++]);
        sb.append("</td>");
        sb.append("<td>");
        sb.append( y[j++]);
        sb.append("</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");
```

But Now if i do a diff between two Xml files  i am not able to see the contents.

If the text is normal , the HTML formed is :

```
 <td>normaltext</td>
```

//rendered properly

if the xml files contains

```
<Hello>
```

tag the html formed contains

```
<td><Hello></td>
```

because of which browser is not able to render it properly.

How can i resolve it ? Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

Problem solved.

---

To be more concrete in your case, just do the following :

```
    sb.append("<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append( x[i++].replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append( y[j++].replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
```

---

According to the comment, this would be even better :

```
    sb.append("<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append( x[i++].replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append( y[j++].replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
```

---

To have <= and >= not replaced, this is working solution, but it is a little nasty :) :

```
    String x = "<Hello>&<=<blabbalal>";
    System.out.println(x.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("&gt;=", ">=").replaceAll("&lt;=", "<="));
```

Has this output :

```
&lt;Hello&gt;&amp;<=&lt;blabbalal&gt;
```

Comment: Before doing those replacements, replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: This is nice. I did these changes and it works well. Just that now in my normal Java code if there is a <=  it also will get replaced. Any solutions which you can think of ?

Comment: @BibinMathew - I added solution, but it does not work for `<` or `>`, if they stay alone.